# ICommand interface not works

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, interface

I have problem with navigation after I have added ICommand interface. Button is still disable and I don't why. For me everythings looks good but if I type in text into Textbox. Maybe binding doesn't work and i don't have value on out. I have tried figure out what's wrong with that code but I don't have idea

RegisterVM

```
public class RegisterVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  //  string connetionString = null;
  //  string sql = null;

    private string _social;

    public string Social
    {
        get { return _social; }
        set
        {
            _social = value;
            Users = new Users()
            {
               Name = this.Name,
               Surname = this.Surname,
               Social = this.Social,                  
            };
            OnPropertyChanged("Social");
        }
    }

    private string _surname;

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _surname; }
        set
        {
            _surname = value;
            Users = new Users()
            {
                Name = this.Name,
                Surname = this.Surname,
                Social = this.Social,
            };
            OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
        }
    }


    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            Users = new Users()
            {
                Name = this.Name,
                Surname = this.Surname,
                Social = this.Social,
            };
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private Users _user;

    public Users Users
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set
        {
            _user = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Users");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public NavigationCandidates navigationCandidates { get; set; }

    private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow;

    public RegisterVM(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
        navigationCandidates = new NavigationCandidates(this);
    }

    public void Navigate()
    {
        _mainWindow.Content = new Candidates();
        _mainWindow.name.Text = string.Empty;
        _mainWindow.Surname.Text = string.Empty;
        _mainWindow.SearchTermTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    public void Register(Users user)
    {
        Users.Register(user);
    }

}
```

}

Users

```
public class Users : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   private string _id;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private string _surname;

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _surname; }
        set
        {
            _surname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
        }
    }

    private string _social;

    public string Social
    {
        get { return _social; }
        set
        {
            _social = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Social");
        }
    }

    private bool _voted;
    public bool Voted
    {
        get { return _voted; }
        set
        {
            _voted = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Voted");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    string connetionString = null;
    string sql = null;

    public void Register(Users User)
    {
        connetionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Anon\\Documents\\Db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
        {
            sql = "insert into Table ([Name],[Surname],[Social]values(@name,@surname,@social)";
            cnn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", User.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", User.Surname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@social", User.Social);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Navigaton

```
public class NavigationCandidates : ICommand
{
    // public CandidatesVM candidatesVM { get; set; }
    public RegisterVM regVM { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    /*    public NavigationCandidates(CandidatesVM canVM)
        {
            candidatesVM = canVM;
        }*/

    public NavigationCandidates(RegisterVM regiVM)
    {
        regVM = regiVM;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        Users user = (Users)parameter;

        if (user != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Surname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Social))
                return false;

            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Users user = (Users)parameter;
        regVM.Register(user);
        regVM.Navigate();
        // candidatesVM.Input();
        // candidatesVM.Navigate();
        // candidatesVM.DeSerializationCamera();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window.Content>
    <Border Background="#202021" CornerRadius="40">
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <Label Content="Type in your data" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Separator/>
            <Label Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="320" MinHeight="32" Foreground="Black" Background="#f5ddff" FontSize="15" FontWeight="DemiBold"
                     TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" x:Name="name" Padding="0,4,0,-2" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxWidth="320" MaxLength="40" PreviewTextInput="SignValidationTextBox"/>
            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Enter Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-35,0,0" Foreground="Black" >
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=name}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <Label Content="Surname" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="320" MinHeight="32" Foreground="Black" Background="#f5ddff" FontSize="15" FontWeight="DemiBold" Margin="0,0,0,10" 
                     x:Name="Surname" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,4,0,-2" MaxHeight="320"  Text="{Binding Surname, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="40" PreviewTextInput="SignValidationTextBox" MaxWidth="320"/>
            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Enter Surname" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-35,0,0" Foreground="Black">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=Surname}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <Label Content="Social" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="320" MinHeight="32" Foreground="Black" Background="#f5ddff" FontSize="15" FontWeight="DemiBold" MaxLength="11" Margin="0,0,0,10"
                     x:Name="SearchTermTextBox" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" Text="{Binding Social, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,4,0,-2" />
            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Enter Social" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-35,0,0" Foreground="Black" >
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchTermTextBox}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <Separator Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="32" MinWidth="120" Foreground="Black" Background="White" Margin="0,45,0,0" Content="Login" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="2"
                x:Name="BtnClk" Command="{Binding navigationCandidates}" CommandParameter="{Binding Users}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Window.Content>
```

MainPage

```
public partial class MainWindow : NavigationWindow
{

    RegisterVM registerVM;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        registerVM = new RegisterVM(this);
        DataContext = registerVM;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any Commands defined in there. Maybe try and put together a little [mcve] ... maybe you'll even find your flaw in the course of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
public NavigationCandidates navigationCandidates { get; set; }


public RegisterVM(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    navigationCandidates = new NavigationCandidates(this);
}
```

You bind your button to a property that doesn't notify.

Comment: So i have to add a notify or bind some where else?

Comment: If you want the binding subsystem to pick up on property changes then yes, you need to notify.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here an example

1 - Create a RelayCommand Class

```
//necessary namespaces
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //For Vs 2015+ 
        return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Can execute changed event handler.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

2 - Create a `ViewModelBase` (preferably abstract class), implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public virtual ICommand NavigateCommand => new RelayCommand(Navigate, o=> CanExecute());

    //You'll override this method in your class 
    protected virtual bool CanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    //You'll override this method in your class
    protected virtual void Navigate(object param)
    {

    }
}
```

3 - Your ViewModel.

```
public class ViewModel: ViewModelBase
{

    protected override Navigate(object param)
    {
        //here you navigate 
    }

    protected override bool CanExecute()
    {
        var result = false;

        //do whatever you want to return true or false;

        return result;
    }
}
```

**note**: - you are mixing MVVM with code behind, you could not for example set the values of your TextBoxes directly in the Navigate method.
I suggest you read materials regarding MVVM Pattern

Answer (score 0):

TextBox Binding isn't wrong , Only thing that I can't see in your code is ICommand Binding in RegisterVM. 
Implement RelayCommand Class in your code and then 
add Icommand property in you RegisterVM like this.

private ICommand _navigationCandidates;

```
    public ICommand NavigationCandidates
    {
        get
        {
            return _navigationCandidates ?? (_navigationCandidates = new RelayCommand(OnnavigationClicked));
        }
    }

    private void OnnavigationClicked()
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to your `NavigationCandidates` class that raises the `CanExecuteChanged` event:

```
public class NavigationCandidates : ICommand
{
    public RegisterVM regVM { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    public NavigationCandidates(RegisterVM regiVM)
    {
        regVM = regiVM;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        Users user = (Users)parameter;

        if (user != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Surname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Social))
                return false;

            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Users user = (Users)parameter;
        regVM.Register(user);
        regVM.Navigate();
    }
}
```

...and call this method whenever the Users is set in the `RegisterVM` class:

```
public Users Users
{
    get { return _user; }
    set
    {
        _user = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Users");
        navigationCandidates.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

You may also want to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the bindings in the view to `PropertyChanged` for the `Button` to become enabled as soon as you have typed something into all three `TextBoxes`:

```
Text="{Binding Social, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```